# SQL Grouping dates by change in value

Tags: sql, hana

would some body help me achieve the below using SQL. Thanks in advance to the community- we wouldn't have done it without you.

Input Data

```
ITEM          YEAR WEEK QTY
SWEETWATER420   201828  1
SWEETWATER420   201829  1
SWEETWATER420   201830  1
SWEETWATER420   201831  1
SWEETWATER420   201832  1
SWEETWATER420   201833  150
SWEETWATER420   201834  150
SWEETWATER420   201835  150
SWEETWATER420   201836  150
SWEETWATER420   201837  150
SWEETWATER420   201838  1
SWEETWATER420   201839  1
SWEETWATER420   201840  1
```

Desired Result

```
ITEM           QTY  BEGINNING YW    ENDING YW
SWEETWATER420   1   201828          201832
SWEETWATER420   150 201833          201837
SWEETWATER420   1   201838          201840
```

Comment: Please tag your DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gap-and-islands problem.  And Hana supports `row_number()`, so you can use the difference of row numbers:

```
select item_qty, min(yearweek), max(yearweek)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by item order by yearweek) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by item, qty order by yearweek) as seqnum_1
      from t
     ) t
group by item, qty, (seqnum - seqnum_1)
order by item, qty, min(yearweek);
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response! This solution worked perfectly.

Comment: I implemented this query couple months ago on SAP HANA 1.00.112.02. The DBA update the database and we are now on version 1.00.122.23 and unfortunately I am getting the error group function is nested. Please advise

Comment: @LearningHero . . . Can you ask another question?  Be clear about the versions you are using.

Comment: I removed the ORDER BY statement and it worked. Thank you